# How to send additional data(location) along with the customer registration form on flutter app using JWT auth plugins' REST API?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, jwt

I am new to flutter and am trying to post customers' location along with the registration from currently i am fetching the location from Google Map. Am not sure that I can POST location along with the current registration form. WordPress plugin - [JWT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/)s' REST API is using to register user, for other purposes like product fetching, category fetching I have used WooCommerce REST API. Just to clear out my question - Can I POST location along with customer registration form on flutter application using JWT auth plugin because currently i don't see any specific columns to save location. Hope you all can understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Is does not seems to be possible with your current setup as the endpoint is not allowing location data to be send.

If you need the location data to be send, you can either created another server (seperated from wordpress) that will communitcate to the wordpress instance and handle authentication. or find another wordpress plugin that enables you to customize the input of a certain endpoint.